# Sorting Y axis on bar chart in day order

Tags: reporting-services

Having some issues sorting the order of my y axis. Want it to be Sun, Mon, Tue etc  Not sure why its coming out in that order. Many Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the Y-axis is ordered in alphabetical order from bottom to up.
If you want to show the days in its proper order, you need to undo that aplhabetical order and arrange the datas in proper order how you want (sun, mon,.. etc).

Also you can do, custom sort, and define new rule to sort datas.
to do so,

select datas, right click and click sort, then in custom sort you can do so!

Comment: Thanks, I have done that, it's partly worked......starts from Thursday at the top though.  how can I get it starting from Sunday?

Comment: tyou can sort data or days, the best possibility will be adding number for days like monday =1, Tuesday=2.....etc or however you want.
And you can sort the data by numbers, Ascending or descending.

You can priorize the days and later sort it how you like!!